# короткие функции mysqli

Tags: php

создал функцию add

```
function add($sql, array $param)    
{    
global $db;    
$str_column = '';    
$str_values = '';    
$array = [];    

foreach($param as $column => $value)    
{
$name_column = explode('/', $column)[0];    

$str_column .= (! empty($str_column) ? ', ' : null).'`'.$name_column.'`';    
$str_values .= (! empty($str_values) ? ', ' : null).':'.$name_column; 

$array[$column] = $value;    
}    

return $db->query('INSERT INTO `'.$sql.'` ('.$str_column.') VALUES ('.$str_values.')', $array);    
}
```

не работает.

```
var_dump    
string(23) "`title`, `type`, `text`"     
string(20) ":title, :type, :text"
```

в ошибке пишет что массив $array лишнее.

помогите исправить или создать такую функцию.

запрос

```
add('table', [    
'test' => $test     
]);
```

Comment: вот как устроена функция https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: _пишет что массив $array лишнее_ правильно пишет https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php, вы что хотите сделать то? Значения вставить? Тогда зачем плейсхолдеры пишете?

Comment: splash58, читал) на моем коде проблема в $array она лишняя) я не профи в php. помогите

Comment: Вы либо начинаете разбираться, либо нанимаете людей которые разбираются. Что сделать тут вам уже указали.

Comment: я хочу чтоб запрос был так add('таблица', ['тест' => 'тескт']);

Comment: вы путаете с каким-то другим синтаксисом, вставляете вместо значений плейсхолдеры `:title, :type, :text` и рассчитываете, что они подставятся из массива (который лишний). Если хотите использовать `query`, то в текст запроса подставляйте сразу значения (предварительно их экранировав)

Comment: версетку нашел в гитхаб версетка pdo. немного изменил его) если можно укажите его что нужно изменить. плейсхолдер убрал

Answer (score 0):

Как то вот так можно, наверное

```
function add($sql, array $param)    
{    
   global $db;    
   foreach($param as &$v) { $v = $db->real_escape_string($v); }
   return $db->query('INSERT INTO `'.$sql.'` (`'.
            implode('`,`', array_keys($param)).'`) VALUES ("'. 
            implode('","', $param) . '")');    
}
```

при вот таком вызове

```
add('mytable', ['a'=>'b', 'c'=>'e']);
```

генерит

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`,`c`) VALUES ("b","e")
```

Comment: работает спасибо) а моя функция отправлял пустую значения.